# How to use binding redirects when dynamically loading assembly with MEF

Tags: c#, mef, .net-4.8, assembly-binding-redirect

I have a .NET 4.8 library that is loaded as a plugin via MEF. That library has automatically generated binding redirects for some of its dependencies:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Channels" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

My main application (.NET 4.8) loads the library assembly dynamically via MEF. When the main application loads the library (e.g. `MyLibrary.dll`), it appears to ignore the binding redirects that are defined in the config file (`MyLibrary.dll.config`) that sits alongside the library assembly, and I get a composition exception because the assembly fails to load:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
1) Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'MyLibrary.MyType'.
Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'MyLibrary.MyType'.
Element: MyLibrary.MyType -->  MyLibrary.MyType -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="MyLibrary, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
Resulting in: Cannot get export 'MyLibrary.MyType (ContractName="LibraryBaseType")' from part 'MyLibrary.MyType'.
Element: MyLibrary.MyType (ContractName="LibraryBaseType") -->  MyLibrary.MyType -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="MyLibrary, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at MainApplication.Start(String[] args) in ...\MainApplication.cs:line 65
   at MainApplication.Main(String[] args) in ...\MainApplication.cs:line 31
```

Is there any way for my application to respect the binding redirects for a dynamically loaded library, if the binding redirects are defined alongside the library assembly? Or am I stuck copy-pasting all of the binding redirects into the app.config of the main application?